# How to draw circular chart with different layer?

Tags: tikz-pgf, charts

I like to use a circular chart with different layers as shown in the attached file. Is it possible to develop in LaTeX? Thank you.
[image]

Comment: Maybe you could show us what you tried so far? So we can identify the problems you have.

Answer (score 5):

Something to start:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[myline/.style={white, line width=1mm}]
\fill[blue!15] (0,0)--(0:4) arc (0:180:4)--cycle;
\fill[red!15] (0,0)--(0:4) arc (0:-180:4)--cycle;
\fill[blue!20] (0,0)--(0:3) arc (0:180:3)--cycle;
\fill[blue!5] (0,0)--(0:2) arc (0:180:2)--cycle;
\fill[red!10] (0,0)--(0:2) arc (0:-180:2)--cycle;
\fill[gray!5] (0,0) circle(1cm);
\draw[myline] (0,0) circle(1cm) circle(2cm);
\draw[myline] (180:3) arc(180:0:3cm);
\draw[myline] (-1,0)--++(180:3cm) (1,0)--++(0:3cm) (0,2)--++(90:1cm);
\draw[myline] (-60:2)--++(-60:2cm) (-120:2)--++(-120:2cm);

\node {A};
\node at (0,1.5) {B};
\node at (0,-1.5) {C};
\node at (135:2.5) {D};
\node at (45:2.5) {E};
\node at (-150:3) {F};
\node at (-90:3) {G};
\node at (-30:3) {H};
\node at (90:3.5) {I};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The answer below uses the [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote.

The gaps between the arcs are obtained with the keys `gap` and `gap radius`.

The figure consists of multiple wheelcharts. A `radius`, `start angle` and `total angle` are specified separately.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfkeys{
  /wheelchart,
  data=,
  gap,
  gap radius,
  slices style=\WCvarA,
  value=1,
  wheel data=\WCvarB,
  wheel data pos=0.5
}
\wheelchart[
  middle=A,
  radius={1}{2},
  start angle=180
]{blue!5/B,red!5/C}
\wheelchart[
  radius={2}{3},
  start angle=180,
  total angle=180
]{blue!20/D,red!20/E}
\wheelchart[
  radius={2}{4},
  start angle=0,
  total angle=180
]{red!15/H,red!15/G,red!15/F}
\wheelchart[
  radius={3}{4},
  start angle=180,
  total angle=180
]{blue!10/I}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```